# Unable to get specific string from Json C#

Tags: c#, json

This is how my json looks like:
[image]

I created the following code:

```
public class user
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public int userid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string red
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string acompaccompelted_setup
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

To get the data from URL I used the following code:

```
string url = "localhost/testingdata/file.json";
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
string jsonValue = "";
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)  
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

user  listing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<user>(json);

Console.WriteLine(listing.username);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to get the value for the string "username". It returns an empty value. If I try to use :

```
List<user> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<user>>(json);
```

Then I'm getting another error. If I call the:

```
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Then I'm getting the complete list of JSON. But I want to extract the username only. I tried to follow steps given here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-json-in-C-Sharp/ but with no success. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a wrapper `UserInfo` class to represent the whole object as follows:

```
class UserInfo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Define the `User` class as follows:

```
class User
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userName", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userId", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long  UserId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "accompletedSetup", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string AccompletedSetup { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "accompletedInfo", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public AccompletedInfo AccompletedInfo { get; set; }
}
```

The `accompletedInfo` property is a complex object. So define a new class to represent it as follows:

```
class AccompletedInfo
{
}
```

Follow the same pattern for all the nested objects. i.e. define a class for each nested object with properties and name of the property in the `JsonProperty` attribute.

Then deserialize using `JsonConvert` as follows:

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(json);
```

The object `user` now has all the properties as expected.

Comment: I tried to apply the suggestion but now I get for this line "            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(jsonValue);
" the following error :Additional information: Could not convert string to integer: 858608032271478784. Path 'user.userid', line 1, position 135.. I tried to apply Convert.ToInt(32)

Comment: Please use bigger datatype like `long` for `UserId` property.

Comment: God! Now it works! You're a star! I spent days dealing with it! I have learned a lot from your comments!

Comment: May I ask you one more questions as this is the first time I'm dealing with JSON and reading a lot, but it seems I still miss something. The previous one works like a charm. I tried to access the complex object and I did it this way trying to follow your suggestion: 
public AccompletedInfo AccompletedInfo { get; set; }

class AccompletedInfo
{
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "completed", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string completed
{ get; set; }
}
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccompletedInfo>(json);
But I get 0 value. Why?